# Hibernate creates two rows instead of one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

pals.

I have an issue with Hibernate's JPA implementation. I use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and PostgreSql v9.

I have two entities with bidirectional connection via OneToMany & ManyToOne:

```
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "shoppingCart", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Good> goods = new ArrayList<>();

public void addGood(Good good) {
    good.setShoppingCart(this);
    goods.add(good);
}

public Good removeGood(Good good) {
    goods.remove(good);
    good.setShoppingCart(null);
    return good;
}

public ShoppingCart() {
}

public List<Good> getGoods() {
    return goods;
}

public ShoppingCart(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

And second entity is

```
@Entity
public class Good {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
@JsonIgnore
private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

public ShoppingCart getShoppingCart() {
    return shoppingCart;
}

public void setShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {
    this.shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
}

public Good(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Good() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Also I use CrudRepository to access ShoppingCart

```
public interface ShoppingCartRepository extends CrudRepository<ShoppingCart, Long> {}
```

And when I'm trying to fill existing cart I have two goods in my database. This is a code to add some goods into existing cart:

```
ShoppingCart cart = shoppingCartRepository.findOne(id);
cart.addGood(new Good("Butter"));
return shoppingCartRepository.save(cart);
```

In table "good" I have now two elements with different PKey and same data

```
5;"Butter";100
6;"Butter";100
```

Why it happens?

Also, when I'm trying to insert breakpoint at repository.save line, I see only one good in goods list in cart.

Comment: try to remove good.setShoppingCart in addGood and removeGood

Comment: I will break connection between cart and good if I remove .setShoppingCart. And even with this, hibernate save instance 2 times

Comment: By the way, if I use Set<> instead of List<>, saving works fine.

Comment: Sorry but with you response i don't know if you tried or not. If it works with a set this is clearly because somewhere the Good object is inserted twice in your goods attribute. With cascade ALL you don't need to set references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is solved.

First way to solve is to make method with save code @Transactional.

Secon way is to use getGoods() instead of goods. We should change this code

```
public void addGood(Good good) {
    good.setShoppingCart(this);
    goods.add(good);
}
public Good removeGood(Good good) {
    goods.remove(good);
    good.setShoppingCart(null);
    return good;
}
```

to this

```
public void addGood(Good good) {
    good.setShoppingCart(this);
    this.getGoods().add(good);
}
public Good removeGood(Good good) {
    this.getGoods().remove(good);
    good.setShoppingCart(null);
    return good;
}
```

getGoods() here forces hibernate to update state of object and everything works fine.

As for me, I use both ways together

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you create a new Good object without id. So Hibernate will generate a new id and persist the new object. If you don't want to create a new object, but only assign an already existing one, you either have to fetch the existing one from the database and assign it to the ShoppingCart oder add the ID if you create the new Good object.

Comment: I want hibernate to make id for me, that's why I use stragety AUTO. In my code I want to get empty cart and insert one new good.